# UISlider events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, uislider

I'm using an UISlider, its updated automatically except the user is touching the sliderbutton. therefore i did this in the function which updates automatically by an NSTimer:

```
if (!isSliderTouched) {
    [progressSlider setValue: progressValue];
}
```

How do I track the ending of this event, when the user releases his finger. I want to set isSliderTouched as long as the user interacts with this control.

**EDIT**: this should be the plot:

1. user beginns draging/touching UISlider => **isSliderTouched = YES**
2. user releases/untouch the UISlider     => **isSliderTouched = NO**

**Solution**:

```
UIControlEventTouchDown
UIControlEventTouchUpInside
[progressSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderMoveStart) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

cheers endo

Comment: I've read this a few times and it's still not clear to me what you want. But TouchUpInside is the event that you listen to when to determine when the user picks there finger up.

Comment: i tried to explain it better, see update

Comment: TouchUpInSide is called twice :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

`- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents`

to detect when the `touchDown` and `touchUp` events occur.  You can set your flag accordingly.

I'm guessing from your code snippet that you are using a UISlider as a progress meter.  Have you considered using a UIProgressView instead?

Comment: thx, for your hint. a UIProgressView hasn't a button to slide, so thats not that what i need

Comment: continuous parameter is what you need  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/continuous

Comment: Not sure around rules on SO, just wanted to indicate to you guys that there is a better way to do this for UISlider controls. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is marked solved, and yet I'd like to add another solution to this that I feel is cleaner.

```
if (!progressSlider.highlighted) {
    [progressSlider setValue: progressValue];
}
```

Comment: A couple of folks voted this down for some reason. 
Maybe I should have explained better:
UISlider objects have a "highlighted" property which is YES when the slider is being touched/dragged. You can use this directly to figure when to update the value and when not to.
If anyone wants to downvote, please let me know what you think is wrong with the answer :)

Comment: For me this method seemed to detect when the slider was first pressed rather than when it was released.

Comment: Max, it actually gives the state (touched or not touched) rather than detecting press or release events.

The person asking the question wanted to set isSliderTouched based on starting/ending events. I am suggesting he can just used the "highlighted" property instead of creating isSliderTouched and figuring out the start and end of the touch.

Comment: I am developing a customized Audio player using UISlider as the progress control. And this is exactly what I need. It's elegant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Better way to track if the user is done interacting with UISlider is to use continuous flag.

If you want to trigger slider action only after the action is complete and user has moved his finger off it then use

```
[blurSlider  addTarget:self action:@selector(blurSliderChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    blurSlider.continuous = NO;
```

Otherwise by default its set to YES.

```
[blurSlider  addTarget:self action:@selector(blurSliderChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    blurSlider.continuous = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

when user touchs the slider you could set a boolean variable flag and make it NO. and in the update method check if the flag is YES or NO.

Comment: i think you missunderstood me. i want that the user can use the slider, but not that the automatic update process does the update while the user is using it.

Comment: than you have to use valueChanged method  or a function that will trigger a function that is connected to valueChanged

Comment: no, when the user has touched the button but is not moving. the automatic update follows.

Comment: than on touch events of the slider you could set a boolean variable flag and make it NO. and in the update method check if the flag is YES or NO.