# Make a NSSlider change data inside a custom NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, delegates

I have a simple OSX application that consists of a NSWindow with a custom NSView (used for drawing) and a NSSlider. When I change the NSSlider's value, I need to update data inside my custom NSView. What is the correct approach to this problem? A delegate? Something else? Please assist me with this matter. Thank you!

Comment: have a look over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664506/uislider-events

Comment: that's for iOS. he's asking about NSSlide

Comment: Thank you, but that's right, I'm working on OSX and not iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the action of your NSSlider to an IBAction in your controller object. When the slider is changed, your action method will get called. Then, in that method, update your model and refresh your view. 
If you still don't understand, be sure to mention what you tried and what's not working.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. I understand, I was just wondering if a delegate wasn't a "better" approach to solve this. Does it make any sense in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking about. As far as I know, this is the only way to use an NSSlider. NSSlider doesn't have a delegate protocol.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking about creating a custom delegate by declaring an (id)delegate object, a protocol, implement the protocol's methods... I'm not sure this would work, and I'm not sure how to define this delegation structure. That is why I decided to ask this here, maybe someone can enlighten me or even tell me I'm totally in the wrong way :)